# Match every object in an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an author collection that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("332ddf"), 
  "authors" : "Mark Twain", 
  "publisher" : "NY", 
  "books" : [ "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", "The Prince and the Pauper" ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ef342"), 
  "authors" : "F. Scott Fitzgerald", 
  "publisher" : "NY", 
  "books" : [ "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", 
              "The Great Gatsby", "This Side of Paradise" ] }
```

I am trying to use the aggregation to create a new collection. For aggregation I tried:

```
db.author.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$books"},
   { $project: 
     { 
        book: "$books",
        authors: ["$authors"]

     }
     }
])
```

but I get `duplicate key error collection` for unwinding the books. How can I get the desired collection using aggregation ?

Comment: You should read the note added to the accepted answer, since it missed something important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need the `$project` stage. All you need to do is "denormalize" the "Books" array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by "book" and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) operator to return an array of "authors".

```js
var cursor = db.getCollection('authors').aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$books" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$books", 
        "authors": { "$push": "$authors" }
    }}
])
```

The aggregation query yields something like this:

```js
{ "_id" : "This Side of Paradise", "authors" : [ "F. Scott Fitzgerald" ] }
{ "_id" : "The Great Gatsby", "authors" : [ "F. Scott Fitzgerald" ] }
{ "_id" : "The Prince and the Pauper", "authors" : [ "Mark Twain" ] }
{
        "_id" : "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer",
        "authors" : [
                "Mark Twain",
                "F. Scott Fitzgerald"
        ]
}
```

BTW the `_id` compound field in your expected result doesn't make much sense so I removed it but if you really feel you need it then simply replace `"_id": "$books"` by `"_id": { "book": "$books" }` in the group stage.

Now let see how we can insert into another collection. one way to do this as mention in the comment below is using the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator which must be the last stage in the aggregation pipeline.

```js
{ "$out": "newCollection" }
```

In case you need to process the result client-side before inserting the document into a new collection you should use "bulk" operation.

#### MongoDB 3.2 or newer

```js
var requests = [];
var count = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(document) {
    // Do something with the document and push a new operation to the stack
    requests.push({ insertOne : document });
    count++;
    if(count % 1000 === 0) {
        db.newCollection.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
        count = 0;
    }
});

db.newCollection.bulkWrite(requests);
```

#### MongoDB 3.0 backwards

```js
var bulk = db.newCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

cursor.forEach(function(document) {
    // Do something with the document and push a new operation to the stack
    bulk.insert(document);
    count++;
    if (count % 1000 === 0) {
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.newCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
})

if (count > 0 )  {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: Actually in the OP's case it would be better to use [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) since it's just going to write the collection directly on the server. Since there is nothing to do client side it doesn't make sense to pull back every document over the wire and rewrite them over the wire. Bulk write protocols were actually introduced in MongoDB 2.6.